# How to Solve for Initial Velocity and Angle?

Tags: physics, projectile-motion

I hope you're having a pleasant day. Wondering if I could ask for your assistance on some projectile problem in 2d plane.

> How do I get the **initial velocity** and **angle** if *maximum
>   height*, *flight time*, *initial height*, *final height*, and *range*
>   are already given?

Basically I just wanted to compute for the *force* needed and the *angle* with the given parameters. The initial height or the initial elevation of the projectile, and the final height or the target elevation can be exchanged -- what I mean by this is the instances where one of them is on the higher ground.

Please also note that I'm very new to interpreting math equations, a step-by-step breakdown of the solution would help me greatly. Very sorry for the trouble.

Please let me know if my question is unclear. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical orbit determination problem. The orbit kinematics for this problem gives

$$
\cases{
y = y_i + v_0 \sin\theta t-\frac 12 g t^2\\
x = x_i + v_0 \cos\theta t
}
$$

now the known numbers give us

$$
\cases{
y_f = y_i + v_0 \sin\theta t_f-\frac 12 g t_f^2\\
x_f = x_i + v_0 \cos\theta t_f
}
$$

also the maximum height condition $\dot y = v_0\sin\theta  - g t^* = 0$ gives us

$$
t^* = \frac{v_0\sin\theta}{g}
$$

and then

$$
y_{max} = y_i + \frac{v_0^2\sin^2\theta}{g}-\frac 12\frac{v_0^2\sin^2 \theta}{g} = y_i +\frac 12\frac{v_0^2\sin^2 \theta}{g}
$$

also we have

$$
d = x_f - x_i = v_0 \cos\theta t_f
$$

Now if you know $y_i, y_f, y_{max}, t_f, d$ you can easily obtain $v_0, \theta, x_f$ assuming $x_i = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $v$ be the initial speed, $\theta$ the initial angle to the horizontal. Let $d$ be the range (ie total horizontal distance travelled. Let $H$ be the maximum height (above the initial height).

The horizontal velocity is $v\cos\theta$ throughout the flight, so $d=Tv\cos\theta$. Hence $v^2\cos^2\theta=d^2/T^2$.

We have $H=v^2\sin^2\theta/(2g)$, so $$v^2=2gH+d^2/T^2$$ Then we get $\theta$ from $d=Tv\cos\theta$.